# Executing a vbs script command by command in java

Tags: java, com, vbscript

I basically want to execute a VBS script in java. For better Information and Flow Control i want to do this for one VB Command at a time. Since the `cscript` tool only executes a whole script, it would be unusable for this. I tried to get it working with Com4J but it is really a pain since i dont know which COM objects the scripts actually use. (for example scripting the SAP-Gui). Is there a way around without generating a bunch of scripts containing only one line each?

Comment: I don't see that generating 1-line scripts would work since it would be missing methods and variables.

Comment: Are you trying to re-invent a VBScript debugger in Java?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [script control](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1949) to load **one** reasonably **structured** (functions, short subs that 'do one thing only') script/library and call/run [selected](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/179a5554-84c5-4f77-b358-76b73b563b82/) items. You also could implement a dispatch sub/function in your VBScript code.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can trigger a `test.vbs` using Java , even if you need parameters to be send you can give a space and add parameter...

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript C://Users//Desktop//test.vbs" + " " + parameter1 
+ " " + parameter2);
```

For a detailed Example Visit: [here](http://www.shabdd.com/sending-automated-mail-without-administrator-rights-on-windows-machine)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your Java program is executing on a Windows machine, try this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("path + MyVBScript.exe");
```

This assumes that your vbscript has been compiled as an executable.

Or:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("path + Cscript + MyScript.vbs");
```

Which uses the Windows scripting host.

Path is the location of your script or executable.